# Find IF a string has a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently faking a social media site. For this fake website i am trying to build a registry box where your password has to contain at least 1 number.

For example: m4aster = true
but: master = an error

i do not care what numbers are in the password just if there are any. my code is:

```
    var count = function hasNumbers(invulveld4)
{
return /\d/.test(invulveld4);
}
if(count = false){
$(".geencijfer").text("Voeg een cijfer aan uw wachtwoord toe.")
};
```

I hope y`all can help me!

Comment: You're not actually calling your function; you typed in a function that takes a parameter, but you're not passing anything to it. You're also using `=` instead of `==` in the `if` statement.

Comment: try using a proper operator in `if` and calling your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the regex. It's your comparison and the fact that you're not calling your function.

Comparison in JavaScript is made with two, or preferably three, equal signs.
Furthermore, with boolean expressions you can skip the actual comparison and shortcut it like so

```
if(!hasNumbers(inputValue)) {
    $(".geencijfer").text("Voeg een cijfer aan uw wachtwoord toe.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var count = function(mydigit){return /\d/.test(mydigit)}
count('master4')
```

count will either return true or false.
In the case of count('master'), count will return false since no digit were found.
In the case of count('master4'), count will return true since the digit a was found.

**update:** 
Try this code:

```
if(count(yourvalue)==false) {
    $(".geencijfer").text("Voeg een cijfer aan uw wachtwoord toe.");
}
```